# Probability that at least one baby born on each day

Tags: discrete-mathematics

At Brokaw Hospital, six babies were born to six different women on Monday through Thursday of a particular week. Assuming that each baby was equally likely to be born on any of the four days, what is the probability that there was at least one baby born on each day? Can someone give me a hint to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Find the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots +x_4=6$ with the restraint that $x_i \geq1$.

Answer (score 0):

$P$(At least 1 baby was born on each day) = $1-P$(Atleast 1 day where no baby was born)

Total number of ways in which babies can distribute over the days = $4^6$.

We will count all possible ways for having atleast 1 day with no baby born.
Let M be the event that no baby was born on Monday. Similarly define events T, W, Th for respective days of the week.

$C(M) = C(T) = C(W) = C(Th) = 3^6$

$C(M\cap T) = C(M\cap W) = C(M\cap Th) = C(T \cap W) = C(T\cap Th) = C(W\cap Th) = 2^6$

$C(M \cap T \cap W) = C(M \cap T \cap Th) = C(M \cap W \cap Th) = C(T\cap W \cap Th) = 1^6$

$C( M \cap T \cap W \cap Th ) = 0 $

Using inclusion-exclusion principle for counting we get the count of cases with at least $1$ day with no baby born:

$C(M \cup T \cup W \cup Th) = 4\times3^6 - 6 \times 2^6 + 4 \times 1^6  = 2536$

So we get our solution as $(4096 - 2536) / 4096 = 0.381$

Small python code to verify it:

```
import random
count = 0
rng = 100000
for i in range(rng):
    mydict = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0}
    for j in range(6):
        mydict[random.randint(1,4)] += 1
    if mydict[1]*mydict[2]*mydict[3]*mydict[4] != 0:
        count += 1
print(count/rng)
```

0.38014